# Embedding images into video on Linux

Tags: linux, video

I want to be able to take a video, and embed images frame by frame, into this video but am having trouble finding where to start. Are there any open source (or paid) libraries that would allow me to do this programatically in Linux?

Comment: Should be doable with `libffmpeg`. Run a decoder and an encoder. Decode to a `buffersink`, insert modify/insert frames, then encode again from `buffer` source. [See here](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Video-Sources).

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to use gstreamer. It's really powerful tool ([Gstreamer picture in picture example](http://www.oz9aec.net/index.php/gstreamer/347-more-gstreamer-tips-picture-in-picture-compositing)).